# Titanium and android sdk problems

Tags: android, titanium

So I'm trying to do this on osx lion with titanium 2.0. Running my code from Titanium directly gets me to the login screen on the emualtor (i've waited on the emulator for a couple of hours) and then it freezes, there is no interaction what so ever, i cant click anything and my app didnt load. So I tried to start a new AVD from the sdk tools but same result, the emulator fires up, loads the main screen and nothing. I did everything possible, gave it 2 gig of ram for the space, tired it on multiple sdk targets (2.1, 2.2, 4.0. 4.1), reinstalled the sdk, same result. Finally I decided to do a "./emulator -avd  -show-kernel" and the output below is the result (i did it both as user and sudo). So what am I missing here? Is it the SDK, Titanium, or the OS? Any help is much appreciated.

```
  s**erial0 console
  Uncompressing Linux................................................................................................. done, booting the kernel.
  Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
  Linux version 2.6.29-gc497e41 (kroot@kennyroot.mtv.corp.google.com) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #2 Thu Dec 8 15:07:43 PST 2011
  CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc080] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387f
  CPU: VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
  Machine: Goldfish
  Memory policy: ECC disabled, Data cache writeback
  Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
  Kernel command line: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
  Unknown boot option `qemu.gles=0': ignoring
  Unknown boot option `android.qemud=ttyS1': ignoring
  Unknown boot option `android.checkjni=1': ignoring
  PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 11, 8192 bytes)
  Console: colour dummy device 80x30
  Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
  Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
  Memory: 512MB = 512MB total
  Memory: 515712KB available (2756K code, 683K data, 108K init)
  Calibrating delay loop... 432.53 BogoMIPS (lpj=2162688)
  Mount-cache hash table entries: 512
  Initializing cgroup subsys debug
  Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
  Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
  CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
  net_namespace: 716 bytes
  NET: Registered protocol family 16
  bio: create slab <bio-0> at 0
  NET: Registered protocol family 2
  IP route cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
  TCP established hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
  TCP bind hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
  TCP: Hash tables configured (established 65536 bind 65536)
  TCP reno registered
  NET: Registered protocol family 1
  checking if image is initramfs... it is
  Freeing initrd memory: 160K
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_interrupt_controller at ff000000 irq -1
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_device_bus at ff001000 irq 1
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_timer at ff003000 irq 3
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_rtc at ff010000 irq 10
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff002000 irq 4
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff011000 irq 11
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_tty at ff012000 irq 12
  goldfish_new_pdev smc91x at ff013000 irq 13
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_fb at ff014000 irq 14
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_audio at ff004000 irq 15
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_mmc at ff005000 irq 16
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_memlog at ff006000 irq -1
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-battery at ff015000 irq 17
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_events at ff016000 irq 18
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish_nand at ff017000 irq -1
  goldfish_new_pdev qemu_pipe at ff018000 irq 19
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-switch at ff01a000 irq 20
  goldfish_new_pdev goldfish-switch at ff01b000 irq 21
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_interrupt_controller
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_device_bus
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_timer
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_rtc
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_tty
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered smc91x
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_fb
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_audio
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_mmc
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_memlog
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-battery
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_events
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish_nand
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered qemu_pipe
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-switch
  goldfish_pdev_worker registered goldfish-switch
  ashmem: initialized
  Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
  yaffs Dec  8 2011 15:06:54 Installing. 
  msgmni has been set to 1008
  alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
  io scheduler noop registered
  io scheduler anticipatory registered (default)
  io scheduler deadline registered
  io scheduler cfq registered
  allocating frame buffer 480 * 800, got ffa00000
  console [ttyS0] enabled
  brd: module loaded
  loop: module loaded
  nbd: registered device at major 43
  goldfish_audio_probe
  tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
  tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
  smc91x.c: v1.1, sep 22 2004 by Nicolas Pitre <nico@cam.org>
  eth0 (smc91x): not using net_device_ops yet
  eth0: SMC91C11xFD (rev 1) at e080c000 IRQ 13 [nowait]
  eth0: Ethernet addr: 52:54:00:12:34:56
  goldfish nand dev0: size c200000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
  goldfish nand dev1: size c200000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
  goldfish nand dev2: size 4000000, page 2048, extra 64, erase 131072
  mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
  *** events probe ***
  events_probe() addr=0xe0814000 irq=18
  events_probe() keymap=qwerty2
  input: qwerty2 as /devices/virtual/input/input0
  goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: rtc core: registered goldfish_rtc as rtc0
  device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
  device-mapper: ioctl: 4.14.0-ioctl (2008-04-23) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
  logger: created 64K log 'log_main'
  logger: created 256K log 'log_events'
  logger: created 64K log 'log_radio'
  TCP cubic registered
  NET: Registered protocol family 10
  IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
  NET: Registered protocol family 17
  NET: Registered protocol family 15
  RPC: Registered udp transport module.
  RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
  802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8 Ben Greear <greearb@candelatech.com>
  All bugs added by David S. Miller <davem@redhat.com>
  VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant c rev 0
  goldfish_rtc goldfish_rtc: setting system clock to 2012-07-25 17:40:43 UTC (1343238043)
  Freeing init memory: 108K
  mmc0: new SD card at address e118
  mmcblk0: mmc0:e118 SU02G 2.00 GiB 
   mmcblk0:
  init: cannot open '/initlogo.rle'
  yaffs: dev is 32505856 name is "mtdblock0"
  yaffs: passed flags ""
  yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.0, "mtdblock0"
  yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
  save exit: isCheckpointed 1
  yaffs: dev is 32505857 name is "mtdblock1"
  yaffs: passed flags ""
  yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.1, "mtdblock1"
  yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
  yaffs: dev is 32505858 name is "mtdblock2"
  yaffs: passed flags ""
  yaffs: Attempting MTD mount on 31.2, "mtdblock2"
  yaffs_read_super: isCheckpointed 0
  init: cannot find '/system/bin/dbus-daemon', disabling 'dbus'
  init: cannot find '/system/etc/install-recovery.sh', disabling 'flash_recovery'
  $ eth0: link up
  warning: `rild' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
  init: sys_prop: permission denied uid:1003  name:service.bootanim.exit**
```

Answer (score 0):

I am actually an Eclipse user but it sounds like it is something wrong with your computer if you can get to the lockscreen of the emulator (correct me if I am wrong about being able to get even there).  Perhaps there is a background task running on your computer or something of that nature. Also, try to restart your computer. Hope this helps though emulators are so spotty that it is hard to tell exactly what is going on.

Comment: So just in case someone stumbles upon this thread, I got this working  here is what I did (not sure what exactly did the trick or if this will work for you) 

1) I uninstalled sdk and titanium
2) I installed mountain lion
3) Installed newest version of xcode
4) reinstalled sdk (its worth noting that the emulator would still get stuck if i ran an AVD directly)
5) reinstalled titanium
6) while doing 5 i noticed a .android folder under my ~ directory with references to AVDs I rm -rf that
7) launched app from titanium and it worked
8) on relaunch i had to rm -rf the .android/avd folder